# If statement with nested if statement not working as intended

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, nested-if

Inside a for loop I have an if statement with a nested if statement inside.
then I have 11 elif statements for the outer if statement all with nested if statements inside.

For example:

`coins =  ['USDT', 'BTC', 'ALPINE', 'USDT']`

```
            for i in range(len(coins) - 1):
                first = coins[I]
                second = coins[i + 1]
               

                if first == 'USDT':
                    if second != 'BUSD' or 'USDC':
                        print('elif Number 1')
                        

                elif first == 'USDT':
                    if second == 'BUSD' or 'USDC':
                        print('elif Number 2')
                        

                elif first != 'USDT' or 'BTC' or 'ETH' or 'BNB' or 'BUSD' or 'USDC':
                    if second == 'BTC' or 'ETH' or 'BNB' or 'BUSD' or 'USDC':
                        print('elif Number 3')
```

The first iteration of the loop works as intended.

With

first = 'USDT

second = "BTC

The first if statement is used and the outcome is
`elif number 1`

The second iteration of the loop doesn't work.

first = 'BTC'

second = 'ALPINE'

The outcome is `elif number 3` which is wrong and the elif statements should filter it into a different outcome.

I have a bunch more elif statements to cover all possible outcomes but it is not being filtered correctly.

What am I missing here?

Comment: pretty sure you're going to need something like `if second != 'BUSD' or second != 'USDC':` since it connects two booleans, and so it will just check if "USDC" is true if it's `if second != 'BUSD' or 'USDC':`. Same for all the others

Comment: i know this has been closed and i probably shouldn't comment since it's like against some stupid rules, but my recommendation would be something like `if second not in ['BUSD', 'USDC']:`